# ¿Cómo puedo agregar una imagen que ocupe 2 o mas filas en Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, bootstrap

Necesito agregar una imagen que abarque 3 filas y una columna.

Si represento el código en forma de matriz, las posiciones [2,3], [3,3] y [4,3] son las que estarían ocupadas por una imagen, mientras que la posición [5,3] estaría ocupada por un `input` que permita importar las imágenes.

El código que tengo es el siguiente (algunas líneas están editadas para que sea mas fácil entender a dónde quiero apuntar):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Nombre (*)">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Apellido (*)">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Documento (*)">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Género (*)">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Fecha de Nacimiento (*)">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Provincia">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Ciudad">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">
    <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
    <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Dirección" ng-model="paciente.direccion">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
    <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
    <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Número" ng-model="paciente.nroDireccion">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Número de teléfono">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
    <input type="email" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Correo Electrónico">
  </div>
```

[image: imagen]

Aclaro que la imagen no es necesariamente el código, sino que lo edité para que sea más fácil de entender.

Comment: Hola Lucas, supongo que al definir la matriz estás tomando primero la fila y luego la columna [5,3] confírmame por favor si lo que deseas es algo como esto: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pzac.png

Comment: Si señor, eso es lo que exactamente estoy tratando de hacer.

Comment: Podría ofrecerte una solución en la cual existan las tres columnas, pero que en realidad cada columna es un conjunto de filas verticales. Visualmente sería igual a tu código.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esto es lo que te propongo.

En lugar de tener las cinco filas, podrías convertir cada una de las filas en columnas verticales (una sobre la otra), esto lo logras primero eliminando la clase [`.row`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid) (la cual crea filas) y segundo agregando la clase [`.col`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid-options) a secas, la cual toma todo el ancho de su contenedor padre, que en este caso sería la clase [`.col-sm-4`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid-options).

En resumen lo que tendrías es tres columnas (`.col-sm-4`) y dentro de cada columna otras cinco columnas (`.col`) que actuarían como "filas".

Como habrás notado, se movió el orden de los [`.form-group`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#forms) dentro del código, esto también cambiaría el orden de verificación de cada uno de los `input`, conocido también como [*focus order*](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/navigation-mechanisms-focus-order.html) (al presionar la tecla <kbd>TAB</kbd> por ej.).
Para corregir este comportamiento usé el atributo global [`tabindex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos_Globales/tabindex), el cual define la navegación secuencial del teclado según como nosotros lo asignemos y no de forma automática.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css">

<div class="container">

  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group col">
      <i class="far fa-address-card"></i>
      <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Nombre (*)" tabindex="1">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col">
      <i class="fas fa-venus-mars"></i>
      <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Género (*)" tabindex="4">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col">
      <i class="fas fa-globe"></i>
      <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Provincia" tabindex="6">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col">
      <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
      <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Dirección" ng-model="paciente.direccion" tabindex="8">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col">
      <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
      <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Número de teléfono" tabindex="10">
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group col">
      <i class="fas fa-address-card"></i>
      <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Apellido (*)" tabindex="2">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col">
      <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
      <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Fecha de Nacimiento (*)" tabindex="5">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col">
      <i class="fas fa-globe"></i>
      <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Ciudad" tabindex="7">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col">
      <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
      <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Número" ng-model="paciente.nroDireccion" tabindex="9">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col">
      <i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
      <input type="email" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Correo Electrónico" tabindex="11">
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group col">
      <i class="far fa-id-badge"></i>
      <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Documento (*)" tabindex="3">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x219?text=Imagen" alt="Imagen">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col">
      <i class="fas fa-paperclip"></i>
      <input type="file" class="form-control text-center" tabindex="12">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Recuerda ejecutar el código a pantalla completa.

Comment: Mil gracias genio, me salvaste!

Comment: ¿Solucionó tu problema, @Lucas? Por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si tu problema se solucionó. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!